# Howto run a specific Ruby 1.9 Test::Unit::TestCase subclass by name

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

The Ruby unit test framework allows subclassing `Test::Unit::TestCase` to create suites of tests.

It is possible to run subsets of tests: all tests in a given .rb file, with a given name e.g.

```
foo.rb -n "testname"
```

or matching a pattern

```
foo.rb -n /pattern/
```

but is it possible to run all tests in a specific suite by specifying the name of the suite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-a` option with the `testrb` command to only run certain tests in your test suite, e.g:

```
$ ls test/
a_test.rb     b_test.rb     c_test.rb

$ testrb -a test/a_test.rb
#... runs a_test.rb only
$ testrb -a test/[ab]_test.rb
#... runs a_test.rb and b_test.rb
```

There's also a pattern matching option, `-p`, but I couldn't get that to work no matter how I tried, or find any examples on the net. Hopefully this will do what you need it to.

Comment: Yes, the issue seems to be that I can run tests by name, or tests by file, but not tests by test-suite e.g. not all the test* methods in a given class where there are more than 1 class in the same .rb file.